# Segmentation fault (core dump) at the end of executing

Tags: c++, linux

I am writing a C++ program on Linux Ubuntu for my class. The program is supposed to find the frequency of a string(s) that user inputs. The frequency is calculated by the number of each character that appears in a sentence and then divided by the maximum characters in a sentence. After that I print out the asterisks based on how many percent of each character appear. Here is the code I wrote

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main(){
string text;//partial text for each whitespace
string finalText;//String that has been concat
int totalLetter=0;//Total number of all letter
double storedValue[26];//Giving Result to each array
int i;//"for" statement counter declaring
int j;//"for" statement second counter declaring
int letters[26];//array to reducing ascii value on line 26
cout << "Enter the text at the prompt to calculate letter frequencies. " << endl <<
        "Enter DONE when finished with the input."<< endl;
while(text!="DONE"){//check the input, if it's not "DONE" then continue adding string
    cout<< "Enter a line of a text: ";
    std::getline(std::cin,text);
    if(text=="DONE")break;
    finalText = finalText + text;
}

char *charArray = new char[finalText.length()+1];//Converting string input to char type
std::strcpy(charArray,finalText.c_str());//Copying string to char


for(i=0; i<finalText.length(); i++){//reduce to smaller case
    if(charArray[i]>='A' && charArray[i]<='Z')
        charArray[i]=charArray[i]+32;
}
for(i=0; i<finalText.length(); i++){//set default for charArray to be 0
    if(charArray[i]<'a' && charArray[i]>'z'){
        charArray[i]=0;
    }
}

for(i=0; i<finalText.length(); i++){//calculate the total characters input
    if(charArray[i]>='a' && charArray[i]<='z'){
        totalLetter++;
    }
}

for(i=0; i<26; i++){//Set all storeValue to be 0 from a - z
    storedValue[i] = 0;
}
for(i=0; i<finalText.length(); i++){//convert letters to start at 0 as an 'a' from ascii code and so on
    letters[i]=(int)charArray[i]-97;
    storedValue[i] = 0;
}
for(i=0; i<finalText.length(); i++){//increment value in array for each letter
    for(j=0; j<26; j++){
        if(letters[i]==j)
            storedValue[j]++;
    }
}
    cout << endl;
cout << "A total of " << totalLetter << " letters of the alphabet were processed" << endl;

    cout << endl;
cout << "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z  %"<<endl;
//calculate the percent
for(i=0; i<26; i++){
    storedValue[i]=round((storedValue[i]/totalLetter)*100);
}

cout<<endl;

//Get Maximum Percent
int maxPercent=0;
int maxLetterPercent=0;
for(i=0; i<25; i++){
if(storedValue[i]>maxPercent){
    maxPercent=storedValue[i];
    maxLetterPercent=i;
    }
}

//Printing asterisk
for(i=0; i<maxPercent; i++){
    for(j=0; j<26; j++){
        if(storedValue[j]>0)
            cout<<"* ";
        else if(storedValue[j]<=maxPercent)
            cout<<"  "; 
}
cout<<" "<<i+1;
cout<<endl;
}

char finalCharMax = maxLetterPercent + 'a';
cout<<"The most common letter is " << finalCharMax << " with a frequency of " << maxPercent
    << " %";

cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After executing, it shows perfect result; the asterisks were in place as they should be.
But my problem occurred when I started to input long sentence, for example I input

> Enter a line of text: **asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd**

and after I input "DONE", it gives junk result, the asterisks were messed up and at the end of executing, it showed the message

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

In this case, what did I do wrong?

Comment: At least *one* loop can go out of bounds for the `storedValue` and `letters` arrays. Other loops might go out of bounds of those arrays or other variables. But, by going out of bounds even one time leads to *undefined behavior* which in turn makes your whole program suspect. I also don't see a need for the dynamically allocated `charArray`.

Comment: You need to learn to use a debugger. It will tell you where it crashes, and you can step through your program to see where your assumptions and reality divide.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, you're right, it was "letters" array, but storedValue is fine. So what I did was I declare the array with size of finalText.length to suit with maximum length of user input! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part of code. The letters array is 26 items lenght and when you are entering long text, stack is corrupted. It leads to segfault at the end of the main() function call.

```
for(i=0; i<finalText.length(); i++){//convert letters to start at 0 as an 'a' from ascii code and so on
    letters[i]=(int)charArray[i]-97;
    storedValue[i] = 0;
}
for(i=0; i<finalText.length(); i++){//increment value in array for each letter
    for(j=0; j<26; j++){
        if(letters[i]==j)
            storedValue[j]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bonus question: why does the corrupted stack lead to a crash _at the end_ of the function? :-)

Comment: @DarkDust return address is kept at the stack as well. It seems this address is corrupting and execution goes to the bad code address.

Answer (score 0):

It's always an indicator that you're overrunning the end of an array if everything works for a short input string and fails catastrophically for a long input string or one with 'unexpected' characters.

Use of a debugger would enable you to pinpoint where you are crashing

Your actual problem is here:

```
for(i=0; i<finalText.length(); i++){//convert letters to start at 0 as an 'a' from ascii code and so on
    letters[i]=(int)charArray[i]-97;
    storedValue[i] = 0;
}
```

as `storedvalue` has only 26 entries, so if your string is 27 or more characters long you'll start overwriting your stack.

In passing, why on earth do you convert your nice std::string to a char array? You're losing a lot of free functionality and checkability when you do that, and the std::string is sufficient for what you need, and as you don't delete[] charArray, you have a memory leak.

I'd not bother doing the checks on length and make storedvalue a 256 entry array (but remember that characters can be signed or unsigned depending on platform). Or better, use a `std::map<char, int>` to hold the counts.

Comment: If you simply increase the size of the `storedValue` array, you would defer the problem, not solve it. Its purpose seems to be to store the number of times an _alphabet character_ has been found in the input, so the array size of 26 makes sense. But it's incorrectly filled, bound checks are needed (and conversion from upper case to lower case).

Comment: @DarkDust not if you increase it to 256 entries you wouldn't. The alphabetical characters are the only results he's interested in but it wouldn't make the code any less efficient to store all the results and then only use the values he's interested in

Comment: This is the wrong thinking, IMHO. Missing bounds checks are always bad as long as you cannot proof that the index cannot go out of bounds. Wasting memory to handle invalid/unwanted input is sloppy. The data is not needed, no need to gather it. The code at this point is simply wrong anyway. If we assume he wants to count or reset the number of times a character has been seen, he's simply not doing that. If we assume he wants to store a zero for every character position in the string, increasing the array's size to 256 is deferring the overflow until you feed it an string with 257 characters.

Comment: Well, that's because he's using the wrong index into the array, it has nothing to do with whether or not he's storing information about the occurrences of punctuation marks and so on. Bounds checks are OK as long as you do the checks on the right bound. However there is no character that is outside the range 0 to 255 (pace signedness), and hence you wouldn't need to check the character is in range. But in general there are better solutions than using arrays under the circumstances